# Distinct Countifs excluding rows with blank value in a specific column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the example below I have some data showing customers that were created during the year (in this case it's only July) and the invoices linked to them:

[image]

I want to calculate the number of unique customer names that have been created in July and have an invoice linked to them. So distinct count on the Name and exclude the blanks on the Invoice#

I have tried using the formula =COUNTIFS(Table1[Year],I2,Table1[Month],I3), but I need to exclude the rows with the blank Invoice# and count only the distinct names.
Any advice?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does your version of Excel support FILTER and UNIQUE?

Comment: Yes it does. Do you have any idea how I can combine them with the countifs?

Comment: You'd just use those two directly, no need for COUNTIFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try-

```
=SUM(--(UNIQUE((FILTER($C$2:$C$14,($D$2:$D$14=I$3)*($E$2:$E$14=$I$2)*($A$2:$A$14<>""))))<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: The result of your UNIQUE() will be an array of the desired names, which would be counted, not summed.  `=SUM(--(arrayOfNames))` should return an error.

Comment: @Max Actually it is counting not summing. Summing logical values is equal counting total items of unique strings after filtering.

Comment: The result of your UNIQUE function is *not* `{TRUE,TRUE,FALSE}` or `{1,1,0}`.  it is `{"Joe","Jane","Pat"}`.  And `SUM(--({"Joe","Jane","Pat"}))` is not going to work.

Comment: @Max If you notice, I have compared that with `<>""` means not empty string to make it boolean and then `--` to suppress those boolean values to number values and then sum up.

Comment: Ah!  Got it, I didn't see that.  Being lazy, my approach would have been to `COUNT()` the array of names costing me 7 keystrokes instead of `SUM(--(  <>""))` which costs me 13. LOL